# Smaller scale for volume dataset in Chart JS

Tags: javascript, dataset, chart.js, scale

I'm graphing some stocks data and I wanted to put the volume in a smaller gray bar dataset at the bottom, like in Yahoo Finance.

## What I want:

The small grey dataset is at the bottom.

[image: screenshot of what I want]

## What I get:

Three different Y scales and the size of the volume dataset is the same a the other.

[image: screenshot of what I get]

## My code:

### When I create the chart:

```js
new Chart(context, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: timestamps.map(n => 
        (new Date(n * 1000)).toLocaleString()
      ),
      datasets: [
        dataset,
        vdataset
      ]
    },
    options: {
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      scales: {
        xAxis: {
          // type: 'time'
          ticks: {
            //autoSkip: true,
            maxTicksLimit: 10
          }
        },
        yAxes: [{
          id: 'volume',
          display: false
        }],
        y: {
          beginAtZero: false
        },
      },
      animation: {
        duration: 0
      },
      plugins: {
        autocolors: false,
        annotation: {
          annotations
        }
      },
      tooltips: {
        mode: 'nearest'
      },
      hover: {
        intersect: false
      }
    }
  });
```

### The volume dataset:

```js
{
    type: 'bar',
    label: `Volume`,
    data: ...,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    borderColor: 'grey',
    fill: 'origin',
    pointRadius: 0,
    borderWidth: 2,
    yAxisID: 'volume'
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to give every dataset a `yAxisID` and then you should name your axis with that id like this:

**Data:**

```
var data = {
  labels: labels,
  datasets: [{
    label: 'My First Dataset',
    data: generateTestSeries(),
    fill: false,
    borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
    tension: 0.1,
    yAxisID: "something",
  },
  {
    label: 'My Second Dataset',
    data: generateTestSeries(),
    fill: false,
    borderColor: 'rgb(182, 50, 192)',
    tension: 0.1,
    yAxisID: "volume",
  },
  ]
};
```

**Scales:**

```
scales: {
    volume: {
        axis: "y",  
        min: -80,
        max: 60,
        position: 'right',
    },
    something: {
        axis: "y",
        min: -20,
        max: 70,
        position: 'left',
    }
}
```

Also you shouldn't have the list yAxes, that was how axes were defined in chartjs 2.x

Here is a fiddle to see this in use: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Jesper02/4d10atzr/13/)

**edit:** If you want an invisible axis just set `display` to `false` as seen in the now updated Fiddle.

Comment: Yes, but would it be possible to make the axis invisible instead of on the right?

Comment: @LuisAFK Yes, I've made edits to my answer to show you how.

Comment: Also, if I wanted to shrink the size of the volume dataset, I could get the `Math.max` of the data and set `max: Math.max(...data) * 5`

Comment: @LuisAFK If you got it working could you upvote and accept this answer? It would really make my day.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot. It's been a while since I used StackOverflow...